# How to forward traffic comming to NON listening port to another listening port using firewalld?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, firewalld

I have server which does NOT listen on port 514. I need forwarding in this way:

request to public_IP:514 ---> redirect to --> localhost:5514

How can I do it using firewalld?